# UIImagePickerController Above UIAlertView

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uialertview

I'm developing an Application in which I need the `UIAlertView` to be present in the background while `UIImagePickerController` is presenting the camera. Currently, the `UIAlertView` is displayed as a superview (above the camera) when camera controller is presented.

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: share your code. what you are doing?

Comment: @Lion Im displaying a custom AlertView with a UISwitch on it. If user turns on the Switch, the Camera should be opened & user can take a picture. After photo has been taken, the Camera Controller should be closed & user should close the alert by himself on clicking the Done button on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlertViews are added to the window and not the controller. They will always be on the top. you can present the picker in an alertview to overlap it.
you can use this library
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraView = [[UIImagePickerController     alloc] init];

cameraView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

cameraView.showsCameraControls = NO;
CustomIOSAlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOSAlertView alloc] init];
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.size.width, screen.size.height)];
    [container addSubview:cameraView.view];
    container.subviews.lastObject.center =  CGPointMake(container.subviews.lastObject.center.x, container.center.y);
    [alertView setContainerView:container];
    [alertView setDelegate:self];
    //    Display the dialog
[cameraView viewWillAppear:YES]; // trickery to make it show
[cameraView viewDidAppear:YES];
    [alertView show];
```

Comment: Great. But, Is it possible to present it on a full screen if added on UIAlertview?

Comment: Full screen alert views are possible

Comment: Cool. Let me try it then.

Comment: Great.. It works.. Getting an exception. Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x16e67b10) of class PLUICameraViewController. Exploring More.. Got an Idea.

Comment: Cleared the exception but setting @Property to CustomAlertView & ImagePicker. Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can show `alertView` and then present `ImagepickerController`. So when you dissmiss that `imagePickerController` you alertView will there on viewController.

Comment: The problem is. UIAlertView remains on top, when camera is presented.

Comment: how you are presenting camera and alertview ? thats why I ask for code. Share your code so i can help